# unicode collation NIF running slower than Pure Erlang implementation

Tags: c, erlang, erlang-nif

I'm trying to optimise existing unicode collation library(written in Erlang) by rewriting it as a NIF implementation. Prime reason is because collation is CPU intensive operation.

Link to implementation: https://github.com/abhi-bit/merger

Unicode collation of 1M rows via Pure Erlang based priority queue:

```
erlc *.erl; ERL_LIBS="..:$ERL_LIBS" erl -noshell -s perf_couch_skew main 1000000 -s init stop
Queue size: 1000000
12321.649 ms
```

Unicode collation of 1M rows via NIF based binomial heap:

```
erlc *.erl; ERL_LIBS="..:$ERL_LIBS" erl -noshell -s perf_merger main 1000000 -s init stop
Queue size: 1000000
15871.965 ms
```

This is unusual, I was expecting it to be probably ~10X faster.

I turned on `eprof`/`fprof` but they aren't of much use when it comes to NIF modules, below is what `eprof` said about the prominent functions

```
FUNCTION                                         CALLS      %     TIME  [uS / CALLS]
--------                                         -----    ---     ----  [----------]
merger:new/0                                         1   0.00        0  [      0.00]
merger:new/2                                         1   0.00        0  [      0.00]
merger:size/1                                   100002   0.31    19928  [      0.20]
merger:in/3                                     100000   3.29   210620  [      2.11]
erlang:put/2                                   2000000   6.63   424292  [      0.21]
merger:out/1                                    100000  14.35   918834  [      9.19]
```

I'm sure, NIF implementation could be made faster because I've a pure C implementation of unicode collation based on binary Heap using dynamic array and that's much much faster.

```
$ make
gcc -I/usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/55.1/include  -L/usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/55.1/lib  min_heap.c collate_json.c kway_merge.c kway_merge_test.c -o output -licui18n -licuuc -licudata
./output
Merging 1 arrays each of size 1000000
mergeKArrays took 84.626ms
```

Specific questions I've here:

- How much slowdown is expected because of Erlang <-> C communication in a NIF module? In this case, slowdown is probably 30x or more between pure C and NIF implementation
- What tools could be useful to debug NIF related slowdown(like in this case)? I tried using `perf top` to see the function call, top ones(some hex addresses were showing) were coming from "beam.smp".
- What are possible areas that I should look at optimising a NIF? For example: I've heard that one should keep data being transferred between Erlang to C and vice-versa minimal, are there more such areas to consider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The overhead of calling a NIF is tiny. When the Erlang runtime loads a module that loads a NIF, it patches the module's beam code with an emulator instruction to call into the NIF. The instruction itself performs just a small amount of setup prior to calling the C function implementing the NIF. This is not the area that's causing your performance issues.

Profiling a NIF is much the same as profiling any other C/C++ code. Judging from your Makefile it appears you're developing this code on OS X. On that platform, assuming you have XCode installed, you can use the [Instruments application](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/index.html) with the CPU Samples instrument to see where your code is spending most of its time. On Linux, you can use the [callgrind tool of valgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html) together with an [Erlang emulator built with valgrind support](http://www.erlang.org/doc/installation_guide/INSTALL.html#Advanced-configuration-and-build-of-ErlangOTP_Building_How-to-Build-a-Debug-Enabled-Erlang-RunTime-System) to measure your code.

What you'll find if you use these tools on your code is, for example, that `perf_merger:main/1` spends most of its time in `merger_nif_heap_get`, which in turn spends a noticeable amount of time in `CollateJSON`. That function seems to call `convertUTF8toUChar` and `createStringFromJSON` quite a bit. Your NIF also seems to perform a lot of memory allocation. These are the areas you should focus on to speed up your code.

Comment: Thanks Steve for your suggestions. Trying to get useful information out of Erlang VM with valgrind support. Interestingly on a Linux machine, NIF version appears faster than Erlang.

Comment: Couple of findings from NIF perf runs: (a) Amount of data being transferred between NIF and Erlang(vice-versa) matter a lot(for larger data transfer i.e. 100KB or more per NIF call, performance can be horrible). (b) Context switch between Erlang <-> NIF isn't cheap, 1M calls with 40 bytes data(40MB aggregate) would take longer to sort than 10K 40KB data.

Comment: There's no real "transfer" of data between a NIF and Erlang, in the sense of copying or such. I suspect what you're seeing is the fact that your `merger_nif_heap_put` and `merger_nif_heap_get` functions do a lot of heap allocations and copying, as I originally pointed out. You should investigate alternative ways of storing and retrieving data that don't involve so much allocation and copying. For example, `merger_item_create` takes two `ErlNifBinary` instances, allocates new memory, and copies them there; instead, why not just store them as `ErlNifBinary` instances?

Comment: Steve, after cleanup w.r.t. mem allocations that could be avoided here is the CPU profile http://imgur.com/wV3oacz of the NIF. From the profile dump(simulating worst case scenario - passing 4KB key & 1MB value), I see majority of time is spent in copying variables from Erlang world to NIF and env_free calls. Any suggestions on what else can be optimised to reduce burden of copying data from Erlang to NIF & also freeing up memory post collation?(updated code sits in github)

Comment: I'll need to clone your repo and take a closer look. I still think you're allocating and copying too much in your put function, but I'll need to take a closer look to know for sure. Any particular command line or shell command you'd recommend for being able to take measurements?

Comment: Steve, much appreciate your useful responses on this thread so far. Updated the git repo with readme. I usually run couple of `perf_*` programs under `erl_prog` along with Instruments utility on mac. Sorry for polluting this SO thread, I hangout on #erlang as sin8h.